# Adding a second router to a home network

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge

I have a home network setup with a Linksys E1000 wireless router. I want to extend my network range to a wider range of the house by adding a second router/switch. The location of the second router is too far to run an ethernet cable between the routers, so I was wondering the best way to connect the two routers wirelessly to share the same internet connection? In looking at some of the other questions and doing some research, it looks like I want to create a wireless bridge or access point. I also found that not all wireless routers support bridge or client mode when there is no cable between the routers and they have to connect wirelessly. Does anyone have a list of routers that can support the wireless bridge mode and communicate with my Linksys E1000 wireless router? I have been told that the Linksys E1000 wireless router does not support this mode without the ethernet cable, so I would have to use it as the main router.

Comment: How about checking out a third party firmware... depends on what version of the E1000 you have if its supported or not.

Answer (score 2):

DD-WRT will fix all those limitations you speak of. Here's a diagram of how it works:

[image]

Here are the details of the [wireless bridging with dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge).

Comment: The diagram shows exactly what I am trying to do. Do I have to update the firmware on both routers or just the secondary router?

Answer (score 1):

You would require a *Wireless Range Extender*.  A handful of routers provide this, and some Wireless Access Points.  You would have to check the specs on the shopping sites to be sure.

I personally use the [Edimax EW-7416APn](http://www.edimax.com/en/produce_detail.php?pd_id=253&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=5) as it's cheap and easy to set up.  In the UK I buy these for around £35.00

Comment: Would the [wireless bridge](http://homestore.cisco.com/en-us/adapters/linksys-WET610N_stcVVproductId65221232VVcatId543809VVviewprod.htm) or [access point](http://homestore.cisco.com/en-us/access-points/linksys-WAP610N_stcVVproductId80342978VVcatId543809VVviewprod.htm) from linksys work with my Linksys E1000 wireless router?

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet runs can be up to 1.5 kilometers long, longer with active routes in between, so at least it's technically possible to just draw a cable. Wireless of course works with less cabling done, it's just less reliable and slower.