# How to connect to wireless router using Dell Optiplex 755?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, desktop-computer, dell-optiplex

I have a  Dell Optiplex 755 (Ultra Small form factor) which according to [the manual](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/opti_755_techspecs.pdf) has a Intel® 82566DM Gigabit LAN 10/100/1000 Integrated on system board.

I use Ubuntu 10.04 but I can not see any network to be discovered in the Network Manager panel, while my netbook (using Ubuntu too) discovers our home ADSL network.

So I am wondering whether the Dell's LAN card is not wireless, and if so what can I do other than cabling my desktop to the router (which is looong)?

I have an spare wireless router; Can I use it to connect to the main router and get the signal to feed the LAN card? If so, how?

Comment: I don't think most desktops come standard with wireless cards, but I could be wrong. See here for a wireless bridge to link your desktop to your router using another wireless router: http://superuser.com/questions/272645/adding-a-second-router-to-a-home-network/272789#272789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no wireless on this system. The details of the LAN card as you've written them do not specify any wireless device.

Most desktops do not come with wireless devices.

Your two options are:
1) purchase a wireless device and install it.
2) connect to your router using a network cord.

Regarding your desire not to wire the connection: Desktop wireless cards generally do not have anywhere near the same range as their laptop brethren. This is usually because the antenna for the wireless radio in a laptop is able to run up inside of the screen, making it rather large and generally at least a foot or two away from anything that would block it.

In order to use your spare wireless router, the device will need to support something called Bridging, which many routers either do not support, or doesn't work even if they do support.

If you absolutely have to use wireless, make sure to get a card (or USB device) that has a seperate antenna that you can place up and away from the actual computer unit so as to extend the range, remove it away from interfering and blocking things, and just generally make sure you have the best possible option.

However, you're running DSL, which means you should be able to plug your modem in at any telephone jack in your house.

Are you certain there are no nearer telephone jacks to your computer than the one you have your modem connected to now?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no telephone jack in my floor. And the distance to the router is > 20m. That's why I'm looking for a wireless solution.

Comment: Do you reckon the USB antennas will be at least as capable as notebooks in receiving signals? Any specific models? Thanks

Comment: No, no USB antennas that I am aware of are as good as laptop antennas. However, since you can't plug a laptop antenna into the device, you have to use something. I recommend any wireless card that has the antennas seperate from the body of the card (or USB plug) and connected by a wire at least 4ft long. This will allow you to set the antennas up and away from the computer and any other obstacles and to place them in a position where they'll receive the best possible signal.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the ultra-small form factor, your best bet would be to purchase a USB Wi-Fi antenna and use that to connect.