# Bridging two wireless routers to extend WiFI range?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge

I have two WiFI routers :

- (A) TPLINK TL3420 connected to internet via 3G USB dongle and is located at "Second floor" of my house.
- (B) ZTE ZXDSL 531 connected to internet via ADSL and is located at "Ground floor" of my house.

Both WiFi routers are sending signals to my "First floor".

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ju3s.png]

Now, I want to have a config which would allow me to access "internet access points" from both the routers all over my house. Basically, make these routers extend each others WiFI access points in their range.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a second router to a home network](http://superuser.com/questions/272645/adding-a-second-router-to-a-home-network)

Comment: The other question address only the possibility of extending a single internet connection to the full wifi network, what I want to achieve is to make both the connections (ADSL and 3G) accessible inside extended accessible range.

Comment: I found this http://jbnote.free.fr/prism54usb/data/documentation/TB-046.pdf describing WDS in detail, both my routers support WDS can this a solution for my issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, this is impossible to achieve with only two devices.
Just to clarify:

- you have two separate internet connections in your house

  - 3G connection (wifi network1)
  - ADSL connection (wifi network2)
- lets suppose you're using a laptop inside your house. You want to be able to connect to _either_ of a 3G connection or to ADSL connection from your entire house

If that is the case, then you could either:

- buy a repeater to extend network1 range
- buy a second repeater to extend network2 range
- throw out one of the internet connections and set one of the routers to propagate other router's signal (it's called WDS broadcast or WDS bridging).

Comment: Yes, if the two WiFI networks act as extenders (each one extending the range of other) wouldn't it be possible to choose the access point of choice anywhere ?

Comment: One WiFi router is able to either host or broadcast only \_one\_ network at a time. One network == one SSID. Note that each network has to have its own channel. If you have two networks, you have two separate channels == two separate frequencies. If one Wifi router would want to extend range of two separate networks, the router would have to switch between frequencies. But if you switch from frequency1 (network1) to frequency2 (network2), you don't hear packets coming from frequency1 (from network1). Windows has Virtual Wifi NIC implementation, but the switch delay is about 500ms (untested).

Comment: Theoretically, if you'd connect with only \_one\_ laptop, those two routers could in deed scan or switch between two networks (at this 500ms interval), but you'd probably had to write the software for that as I don't know of any software that is able to perform such a task.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly WiFi repeaters that would retransmit the signal however, I have not seen one that will do this for two signals.  What is the reason you wish to access both APs? Would it work to havea  repeater for one only to cover the whole house?

Comment: The ADSL internet in my home-office is switched "ON" only during the day and 3G in night. Also, having access to both access-points gives me leisure to access internet when a single link is down (happens quite frequently here).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything said by trismarck, and I would like to present another option.

- feed both connections to a load balancer (on the ground floor)
- have an extra router on the first or second floor to bridge the connection all
  over the house.

This is probably the most expensive of the solutions offered, but it gives several advantages:

1. You can use both connections to the fullest from the same machine at the same time.
2. LBs are greatly customizable. You can script or configure any kind
   of connection split.
3. Wifi connections are probably gonna improve sligthly because of
   lessened noise from using only one channel instead of two.

Comment: Hmmm, I dont want to invest more money into this if this can be achieved without absolutely requiring that. What I am thinking why cant the WiFI networks act as extenders to each other as both of them are able to see each other ?

Comment: they can see each other, but most likely can broadcast on one channel at the time. In other words, regular APs aren't made for what you intend to use them. Having both connections routed to one channel get s close to what you want to do, with some added advantageds and costs